# Find columns with different values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe has 120 columns.Suppose my dataframe has the below structure

```
Id  value1 value2 value3
a    10     1983  19
a    20     1983  20
a    10     1983  21
b    10     1984  1
b    10     1984  2
```

we can see here the id **a**, **value1** have different values(10,20). I have to find columns having the different values for a particular id. Is there any statistical or any other approach in spark to solve this problem?
Expected output

```
   id new_column
   a value1,value3
   b value3
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @yaron I have updated my question with expected output. Thanks

Comment: now the question is clear, I'll update when/if I'll find an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code might be a start of an answer:

```
val result = log.select("Id","value1","value2","value3").groupBy('Id).agg('Id, countDistinct('value1),countDistinct('value2),countDistinct('value3))
```

Should do the following:

1)

```
log.select("Id","value1","value2","value3")
```

select relevant columns (if you want to take all columns it might be redundant)

2)

```
groupBy('Id)
```

group rows with the same ID

3)

```
agg('Id, countDistinct('value1),countDistinct('value2),countDistinct('value3))
```

output : ID, and number(count) of unique(distinct) values per ID/specific column

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways, one of them being the `distinct` method, that is similar to the SQL behaviour. Another one would be the `groupBy` method, where you have to pass in parameters the name of the columns you want to group (e.g. `df.groupBy("Id", "value1")`).

Below is an example using the `distinct` method.

```
scala> case class Person(name : String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val persons = Seq(Person("test", 10), Person("test", 20), Person("test", 10)).toDF
persons: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> persons.show
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
|test| 10|
|test| 20|
|test| 10|
+----+---+

scala> persons.select("name", "age").distinct().show
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
| test| 10|
| test| 20|
+-----+---+
```